# Sorting list of complex elements like Gray code is organized

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of complex elements, namely tuples containing a predefined number of numbers, here is a small example:

`[(2, 3, 5), (1, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7)]`

I need to sort this list in the same way than Gray code is organized, meaning that only one element of the tuple can change from one item to the next. Order of the numbers in the tuples is important. Example:
`(1, 5, 6)` can be followed by `(1, 3, 6)` or vice-versa.

The first tuple in the resulting list can be any of the tuple in the initial list.

If a tuple cannot be placed according to the rule in a group of consecutive tuples, than it should be placed within another group where the rule can be applied. Example:
`[(2, 3, 5), (1, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7)]`
can be sorted such as:

`[(1, 5, 6), (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 5)]`

or

`[(2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 7), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 6), (1, 5, 6)]`

The goal is to limit the number of changes when passing from one element to another, and obviously in total when considering the full list. The following list would not be optimal because it has a total number of changes of 6 (1+1+3+1=6) when the one before had only 5 changes in total:

`[(1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 7)]`

Has anybody encountered such an algorithm?

Comment: Though I don't know of an algorithm specifically designed for this situation, it can clearly be represented as a weighted total graph (tuples being vertices, with edges weighted with the distance between 2 tuples); thus graph traversal algorithms should help. @trincot: I'm pretty sure OP means that you compare 2 tuples position by position, but the distance is symmetric (thus if tuple1 -> tuple2 is allowed, tuple2 -> tuple1 too). Perhaps you're confusing order **in** the tuples with order **of** the tuples.

Comment: I found an article relevant to my idea (though I didn't read it in depth): https://www.baeldung.com/cs/shortest-path-visiting-all-nodes ; this allows to visit a node several times, but perhaps the algorithms can be adapted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, this problem relates to [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) (visit each node only once, minimizing cost).

This is hard problem to solve, but you can try to use `networkx` (which has methods for TSP):

```py
import networkx as nx

tsp = nx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem
SA_tsp = nx.approximation.simulated_annealing_tsp

lst = [(2, 3, 5), (1, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7)]

cost_func = lambda a, b: sum(c != d for c, d in zip(a, b))

# construct complete graph from `lst` (each node is connected to each other node)
G = nx.complete_graph(len(lst))
for e in G.edges():
    a, b = lst[e[0]], lst[e[1]]
    # each edge has custom weight (e.g. going from (2, 3, 5) to (1, 5, 6) has cost 2
    G[e[0]][e[1]]["weight"] = cost_func(a, b)

# compute TSP (this is taken from the example in their doc page)
# https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.traveling_salesman.traveling_salesman_problem.html
method = lambda G, wt: SA_tsp(G, "greedy", weight=wt, temp=500)
p = tsp(G, cycle=False, method=method)

p = [lst[i] for i in p]
cost = sum(cost_func(i, j) for i, j in zip(p, p[1:]))
print(f"{p=} {cost=}")
```

Prints:

```
p=[(2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 7), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 6), (1, 5, 6)] cost=5
```

Comment: Can you consider explaining the code? Will be helpful for others. Code Comments will help too.

Comment: @NusabTaha-Nusab19 I've added some comments.

Comment: Oh you're right, I should have thought of the TSP; a slight difference though, you don't have to come back to the start.

Comment: This is a good approach which probably gives a near perfect result in many cases and in my case it is good enough. I thought of TSP but I didn't know of any library and how to use them. Thank you.

Comment: I guess this is the location of the networkx lib: https://pypi.org/project/networkx/

Comment: @Toady Yes, this is the location I've installed it from too. `pip install networkx`